# How to Update State While Device Orientation Changes

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I am trying to update state while changing device orientation in riverpod but getting some following errors

**StateNotifierListenerError (At least listener of the StateNotifier Instance of 'KeyBoardResize' threw an exception
when the notifier tried to update its state.
The exceptions thrown are:
Tried to modify a provider while the widget tree was building.
If you are encountering this error, chances are you tried to modify a provider
in a widget life-cycle, such as but not limited to:

- build
- initState
- dispose
- didUpdateWidget
- didChangeDepedencies
  Modifying a provider inside those life-cycles is not allowed, as it could
  lead to an inconsistent UI state. For example, two widgets could listen to the
  same provider, but incorrectly receive different states.**

This is Logic have Written

```
class KeyBoardResize extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  KeyBoardResize() : super(false);

  changeBool(mode) {
    if (mode == Orientation.landscape) {
      return state = true;
    } else if (mode == Orientation.portrait) {
      return state = false;
    }
  }
}

final keyboardResizeNotifier =
    StateNotifierProvider<KeyBoardResize, bool>((ref) => KeyBoardResize());
```

This is how i used in widget

```
class LoginScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final bool keyboardEnabled =
        WidgetsBinding.instance.window.viewInsets.bottom <= 0.0;

    final resize = ref.read(keyboardResizeNotifier);

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: resize,
      body: OrientationBuilder(
        builder: (context, orientation) {
          if (orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
            ref.read(keyboardResizeNotifier.notifier).changeBool(orientation);
            return portraitMode(context, keyboardEnabled);
          } else if (orientation == Orientation.landscape) {
            ref.read(keyboardResizeNotifier.notifier).changeBool(orientation);
            return landscapeMode(context, keyboardEnabled);
          } else {
            return Container();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ref.watch` in the `build` method:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final bool keyboardEnabled =
        WidgetsBinding.instance.window.viewInsets.bottom <= 0.0;

    final resize = ref.watch(keyboardResizeNotifier);

    return Scaffold(...)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check mounted property

```
  class KeyBoardResize extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  KeyBoardResize() : super(false);

  changeBool(mode) {
  if(!mounted)return;

  if (mode == Orientation.landscape) {
    return state = true;
  } 
  else if (mode == Orientation.portrait) {
   return state = false;
   }
 }
}
```